# Error in VB.NET mysqldump export with two conditions

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem exporting my desired output. I want to use `'AND'` in the where clause but it's not working. But when I use only one of the condition ex. --`where=clientid='" + clientid + "'`, it's working. But when I add `status=''`, its not working anymore. What is my error here? Thanks!

Code:

```
Sub Export()
    Dim file As String
    Dim clientid = frmDashboard.txtClientID.Text
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "SQL Dump File (*.sql)|*.sql|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "CUST" + clientid + ".sql"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        file = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim myProcess As New Process()
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        myProcess.Start()
        Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
        Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
        Dim status = ""
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysqldump -u administrator --password=password --skip-add-drop-table --no-create-info -h localhost cashloan clientcustomers --where=clientid='" + clientid + "' and status=''> " + file + " ") 'clientcustomers --where=clientid=" + clientid + " 
        myStreamWriter.Close()
        myProcess.WaitForExit()
        myProcess.Close()
        MsgBox("Export was finished successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Export")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. I added double quotes.

```
--where=""status='" + status + "' and clientid='" + clientid + "'""
```